# How do you add in a new target for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I received a Xamarin Forms PCL project from another developer that has a Droid and an iOS target.  Apparently, they had removed the Windows Universal version.  How do you add back in a Windows Universal target?

Comment: you just add a new project to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason mentioned, you simply have to add a new project to you solution.

All you have to do, is:

1. Right-click on your solution
2. Click `Add`
3. Click `New Project`
4. Choose `Blank App (Universal Windows)

After the project has been added to your solution, you will have to add the `Xamarin.Forms` package from the NuGet manager:

1. Right-click on the new project
2. Click `Manage NuGet Packages`
3. Add the latest `Xamarin.Forms` package

Afterwards, you have to add a reference to your PCL project from the new Windows Universal project. You do so by:

1. Right-clicking your project
2. Choose `Add`
3. Click `Reference` and choose your PCL project

Now you simply have to configure your application, which is described in more detail in [this post](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/platform-features/windows/installation/universal/).

Comment: Thank you!  I am very new to VS.net programming - this helped a lot!